# How can I prevent TextVectorization in Tensorflow creating values for Unknown and blank strings?

Tags: python, encoding, tensorflow2.0, one-hot-encoding

I am looking to one hot encode string tensor as part of my dataset pipeline. It seems to me this can be achieved using `TextVectorization` to get an integer representation of the string tensor and then `one_hot` to convert to achieve the encoded 2d tensor.

When i use TextVectorization it seems to automatically try to map "" to 0 and strings out of vocabulary strings to 1. See below using Tensorflow 2.3:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers

possible_values = ["a","b","c"]
text_vectorization = layers.experimental.preprocessing.TextVectorization(output_sequence_length=1)
text_vectorization.set_vocabulary(possible_values)

print(text_vectorization.get_vocabulary())

['', '[UNK]', 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

I can see why it would be useful as it would handle the last 2 values in the below tensor without throwing an error and creating a feature for them in the process.

```
test_tensor = tf.constant(["b","b","c","b","a","potato",""])

print(text_vectorization.call(test_tensor))

tf.Tensor(
[[3]
 [3]
 [4]
 [3]
 [2]
 [1]
 [0]], shape=(7, 1), dtype=int64)
```

In my application though I want to switch this behaviour off as I don't need it. [The documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.3/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/experimental/preprocessing/TextVectorization) doesn't seem to provide an option to disable it and for now I am just going to -2 from the output but that doesn't feel right.

Are there any cleaner, tensorflow native, solutions for generating integer representations of string tensors?

Comment: you can write code which will create new list without these elements - simply use `for`-loop to get elements from list and check `if element in possible_values:`. If elements is in `possible_values` then add this to new list.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove elements then you need normal `for`-loop to filter it

```
data = ["b","b","c","b","a","potato",""]
possible_values = ["a","b","c"]

filtered_data = []

for item in data:
    if item in possible_values:
        filtered_data.append(item)

print(filtered_data)
```

or shorter with list comprehension

```
data = ["b","b","c","b","a","potato",""]
possible_values = ["a","b","c"]

filtered_data = [x for x in data if x in possible_values]

print(filtered_data)
```

So all this doesn't need any special functions.

Comment: Hi, I already know that my data will only contain ["a","b","c"] so I shouldn't need to filter. I was just wondering if I was missing an obvious way to avoid the ['', '[UNK]'] values in the vocabulary of the TextVectorization. I don't think there is. I will stick with the -2 for now otherwise  subsequently creating an array with tf.one_hot will always contain 2 columns that are always 0.